# What Flash Framework For Soccer game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flixel, citrus-engine

I'm a new Flash games developer, i just created my first game in Flash using FlashPunk, it was great, now i'm supposed to create a single player vs cpu soccer game, exactly like this one : [Kung Foot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g24-H3fJyv0).

As i said, i find FlashPunk a good Framework, but i'm opting for better performance and heavy graphics, i'm actually think about either Citrus or Flixil.

They both use Box2D for collisions, but i've heard that Citrus would be the right choice if it was a platform game.

I don't know if there are any other well documented Frameworks out there, what do you think !

Answer (score 2):

I think [starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) is best decision in your case.

Comment: .. Thank you for your reply, can i ask why do you think Starling is a better one than Flixel ?

Comment: I have never used and I don't know features of Flixel, but I can say why starling is good engine for you, 
1. it's cross platform
2. it has good Performance
3. great graphic (you can make absolutely same thinks what you have in your design file)
4. and what is important for you it's ideal for platform games, I advise you from my practice
if my answer is helpful, please, vote up :)

Comment: if you gonna make games... I think the best way for this is unity... it's more simple than any flash framework

Comment: .. I see, but i was thinking that the game i'm trying to make is not a platform game, and when it comes to cross platform the game is meant to be only on Flash.

Comment: .. Exactly, in fact the game will also be created on Unity by another team member, i'm the responsible for the Flash version.

Comment: if you write on Unity, why do you try to make flash version?

Comment: .. Because the use the games of unity in the browser you need a specific plugin, not well known as Adobe Flash

Comment: you can build unity as swf

Comment: ..Check this one mate : http://techcrunch.com/2013/04/24/flash-takes-another-step-towards-death-as-unity-drops-support/

Comment: i decided to use Straling just like you suggested, i managed to use also Box2D, i'm trying to set Spine as well, but i can't get a way to use it with Box2D, do you have any idea howa that can be done ?

Answer (score 2):

Citrus isn't really an engine as much as it is a collection of other tools to make development easier. It takes a rendering engine (like starling or away3D) and a phyics engine (like nape or box2d) and bundles them together for you, providing some functionality to make the process of using them easier. (Like the ability to add a virtual joystick to the screen in [one line of code.](http://citrusengine.com/api/citrus/input/controllers/starling/VirtualJoystick.html) However, you could do all of these things on your own and be just as successful.

If you plan on using Citrus, be very careful. It's great for getting stuff up and running quickly, but the documentation can be very iffy sometimes. For example SimpleCitrusSolver is used in a lot of their tutorial documentation, but [it is broken in newer versions.](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/citrus-engine-simple-solver) I recommend reading about the logic behind every library function you use from citrus, instead of letting it be a magic library that does nape and starling for you.

As far as what framework is the best, it's really a personal choice. They all will let you accomplish the things you want to do, just go with what feels the most comfortable.

Comment: .. That's a great way to see thing, and yes i couldn't agree more when it comes to the Documentation, i started working with Starling and i was hoping i'll get to use Spine framework on the way to get the benefit of Skeleton animations, still i can't find good resources out there, i'm all ears for any advice  :)

Comment: Whenever I want to knock out a graphical application, I use LibGDX. There isn't any particular reason (other than the fact I know it will run on anything I want it to, and I'm very comfortable with Java). 

My best advice is to take something and run with it. There is no best framework for making soccer games.